# Simple way to transform numpy array to stack along different depth dimension

Tags: numpy

I am attempting to transform a numpy ndarray in the following manner.

Here is the array I have currently given by rot_F:

```
# F is laid out to be human readable here
F = np.array(
    [ 
        [# Filter 0
             [ # Depth 0
             [1, -1],
             [2,  0]
             ],
             [ # Depth 1
             [ 0,  0],
             [-1, -1]
             ]
        ],
        [# Filter 1
             [ # Depth 0
             [0, -1],
             [3,  0]
             ],
             [ # Depth 1
             [ 1,  2],
             [-1, -1]
             ]
        ]
    ]
    )

F = np.moveaxis(F,1,3)

# rotate F by 180 degrees along axes (1,2)
rot_F = np.rot90(F,2,(1,2))

print(rot_F)

OUTPUT FROM print(rot_F):
[[[[ 0 -1]
   [ 2 -1]]

  [[-1  0]
   [ 1  0]]]

[[[ 0 -1]
  [ 3 -1]]

  [[-1  2]
   [ 0  1]]]]
```

Now I want to turn rot_F into the following:

```
desired_filters = np.zeros_like(rot_F)
desired_filters[0,:,:,0] = np.array([[0,2],[-1,1]])
desired_filters[0,:,:,1] = np.array([[0,3],[-1,0]])
desired_filters[1,:,:,0] = np.array([[-1,-1],[0,0]])
desired_filters[1,:,:,1] = np.array([[-1,-1],[2,1]])


print(desired_filters)

OUTPUT FROM print(desired_filters):
[[[[ 0  0]
   [ 2  3]]

  [[-1 -1]
   [ 1  0]]]


  [[[-1 -1]
    [-1 -1]]

   [[ 0  2]
    [ 0  1]]]]
```

Basically I am trying stack all of the arrays on 0th depth dimension in rot_F along their own depth dimension and all of the arrays on the 1st depth dimension in rot_F on their own depth dimension while preserving the original shape.

Comment: Make sure you understand `np.rot90`.  In its code I see the use of `transpose` and `flip`.  `flip` is `[::-1]` indexing.

Comment: With those initial `F` values, identifying what has changed in `rot_F` or the desired output is tedious. There's no obvious pattern.

Comment: In rot_f each 2d array is rotated by 180 degrees. In the desired output all 2d arrays at depth 0 are now stacked along their own depth axis and likewise for depth 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error with `transpose`:

```
In [157]: rotF = np.rot90(np.moveaxis(F,1,3),2,(1,2))
In [158]: rotF
Out[158]: 
array([[[[ 0, -1],
         [ 2, -1]],

        [[-1,  0],
         [ 1,  0]]],


       [[[ 0, -1],
         [ 3, -1]],

        [[-1,  2],
         [ 0,  1]]]])
In [159]: F1 = rotF.transpose(3,0,1,2)
In [160]: F1
Out[160]: 
array([[[[ 0,  2],
         [-1,  1]],

        [[ 0,  3],
         [-1,  0]]],


       [[[-1, -1],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[-1, -1],
         [ 2,  1]]]])
In [161]: F1.transpose(0,2,3,1)
Out[161]: 
array([[[[ 0,  0],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[-1, -1],
         [ 1,  0]]],


       [[[-1, -1],
         [-1, -1]],

        [[ 0,  2],
         [ 0,  1]]]])
```

That `F1` intermediate stage was

```
In [110]: G =np.array([np.array([[0,2],[-1,1]]),
     ...: np.array([[0,3],[-1,0]]),
     ...: np.array([[-1,-1],[0,0]]),
     ...: np.array([[-1,-1],[2,1]])]).reshape(2,2,2,2)
In [111]: G
Out[111]: 
array([[[[ 0,  2],
         [-1,  1]],

        [[ 0,  3],
         [-1,  0]]],


       [[[-1, -1],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[-1, -1],
         [ 2,  1]]]])
```

Or in short:

```
In [163]: rotF.transpose(3,1,2,0)
Out[163]: 
array([[[[ 0,  0],
         [ 2,  3]],

        [[-1, -1],
         [ 1,  0]]],


       [[[-1, -1],
         [-1, -1]],

        [[ 0,  2],
         [ 0,  1]]]])
```

It's hard to picture, but apparently you just wanted to swap the first and last axes.

---

Looks like `rot_F` is also

```
np.rot90(F,2,(2,3)).transpose(0,2,3,1)
F[:,:,::-1,::-1].transpose(0,2,3,1)
F.transpose(0,2,3,1)[:,::-1,::-1,:]
```